# Neovim - Async function to prevent blocking buffer

Tags: vim, neovim

I'm attempting to create a small function in Neovim that executes `tslint`. The current version of the function however blocks my editor (not able to scroll through my buffer while it's running). How do I make these function run async so the rest of neovim is still usable?

```
Plug 'jaawerth/nrun.vim'

function! TslintFix()
  let tslint = nrun#Which('tslint')
  if filereadable(tslint) && filereadable(nrun#Which('prettier'))
    silent exec '!' . tslint . ' --fix ' . expand('%:p') . ' > /dev/null 2>&1'
    e!
  endif
endfunction
autocmd! BufWritePost *.ts :call TslintFix()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use "w0rp/ale" for your purpose.

- ale is an asynchronous linter(fixer).
- ale is supported `tslint`, of course.